# How to draw a tree graph based on Graphviz traversal

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, random-forest

I'm trying to visualize all the trees in the random forest, but it's hard to visualize while walking through it. You can only store a list and print it once. Is there a way to visualize it directly as we walk through it?
`

```
l = []
feature_dataframe = df.iloc[:, 0]
class_dataframe = ["Ginebra","雪莉","贝尔摩德"]
for tree in rfc.estimators_:
    doct_ = export_graphviz(
    decision_tree=tree,
    feature_names=feature_dataframe,
    class_names=class_dataframe,
    filled=True,
    rounded = True,
    impurity=True)
    graph = graphviz.Source(doct_)
    l.append(graph)
```

`

Comment: Please say more about what this might look like - or not look like.

Comment: That said, I wanted to use Graphviz visualization in the for loop, but it didn't seem to work